# Calculate Limit 0f nested square roots

Tags: limits, nested-radicals

It is an interesting task to try finding the limit of nested square root expressions.

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( 1 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3+ ... + \sqrt {n + \sqrt{n+1}}}}\right)$$

How to solve this one?

Comment: Relevant: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/437209/) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/201193/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the square of the [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html), which converges, but is not known to possess a closed form. See also [Somos's Quadratic Recurrence Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html).

Answer (score 5):

Convergence of this nested radical expression can be seen by *Herschfeld's convergence test* (see Herschfeld, On Infinite Radicals. *Amer. Math. Monthly* 42, 419-429, 1935.):

> **Theorem:** For $0<p<1$ and $a_n\ge 0$, the limit
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_1+(a_2+(\cdots+(a_n)^p)^p)^p$$
>   exists if and only if the sequence $(a_n^{p^n})_n$ is bounded.

That reduces checking convergence to seeing that $a_n^{p^n}=n^{2^{-n}}$ is bounded, which is clear since

$$n^{2^{-n}}=e^{2^{-n}\log n}\longrightarrow 1$$

as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

However, no closed form is known to express the limit.

Comment: This is probably a long shot, but since you mentioned [Herschfeld](http://www.pballew.net/1935Herschfeld.pdf), I have to ask: is there any deeper meaning to his observation that continued fractions are nested radicals of order $-1$ ? Some implications, perhaps ? Thank you.

Comment: @Lucian No, as far as I remember he just remarks that and nobody really knows what that is good for. At least I'm not aware of any implications.